# why are du -b and du -k different so much

Tags: du

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, and the version of du is 8.25. Now I have a question:

```
$ du -b /var/log/lastlog
69788251412 /var/log/lastlog
```

the size matches command ls -al.
While I use du -k, it has another result:

```
$ du -k /var/log/lastlog
80 /var/log/lastlog
```

The two result doesn't match, why?

Answer (score 1):

`/var/log/lastlog` is a binary file used in "random access" mode rather than a log appended to, and is thus naturally a [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), as [noted in this (GNU/Linux) manual](https://manpages.debian.org/login/lastlog.8#NOTE):

> [NOTE](https://manpages.debian.org/login/lastlog.8#NOTE)
>
> The lastlog file is a database which contains info on the last login
> of each user. You should not rotate it. **It is a sparse file**, so its
> size on the disk is usually much smaller than the one shown by "ls -l"
> (which can indicate a really big file if you have in passwd users with
> a high UID). You can display its real size with "ls -s".

Sparse means its actual disk usage is less than its apparent size.

On GNU/Linux, the [`-b`](https://manpages.debian.org/coreutils/du.1#b) option for `du` is described as:

> `-b`, `--bytes`
>
> equivalent to `--apparent-size --block-size=1`

That is, `-b` explicitly disables the sparse file detection and handling by including `--apparent-size`.

So to have size in bytes match `-k` (on-disk actual usage) use instead:

```
du --block-size=1 /var/log/lastlog
```

or to have size in KiB match `-b` (with apparent size) use instead:

```
du --apparent-size -k /var/log/lastlog
```